# mySQL, type and length recommendation for Twitter message

Tags: mysql, twitter, tweets

I'm looking to store Tweets in mySQL. I would only need the message body and am looking for a recommendation as far as type and character length. Varchar or Text, if either of those.. how long? Tweets are limited to 140 characters, but I know there is a series of possible gotchas like re-tweets, @'s and links. Anybody went down this path? What worked for you?

I found this but this relates to the user name and not the message..

[Twitter name length in DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335636/twitter-name-length-in-db)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think VARCHAR(255) is best for you. There isn't much reason to make a VARCHAR less than 255 since it is a variable length string it takes the same amount of space to store whether you limit it to 255 or 200. I don't think you have need for a TEXT data type. Side note, just in case: Watch out for injection attacks. Don't trust tweets, haha.

Answer (score 0):

varchar can be used up to 255 i think that is more than enough buffer space for the gotchas.
even though i think you may be able to get by with varchar 200

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it depends on the storage engine you are using. As VARCHAR fields, as opposed to TEXT fields, are stored in-row for the MyISAM storage engine. (I'm not sure but it seems there is not much difference when using innoDB)

So I would go with varchar.